# Integrate & simplify in Maple

Tags: maple

I'm new to `Maple`.
I want to integrate and simplify the following expression:

```
int(((1 - r*cos(x-t)))/(1+r^(2)-2* r*cos(x-t)), x=0..2*pi,AllSolutions=true) 
assuming t>=0, assuming r>=0, additionally t <=2*pi, additionally r<=1;
```

If I just run the `int` line itself, I'm getting very confusing expression.
Int and assume lines are giving me error, 
if `smb` could help me out with that,
thanks!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. I think that you should correct your post. Add code formatting. Attach exception that you receive. Remove some unnecesary sentences such as 'I am new', 'Thanks'. If you do the following you will increase your chances to getting answer.

Comment: The sentence "I'm new to Maple" is useful here. It indicates that you likely meant to use `Pi` rather than `pi`.

Answer (score 1):

Do you know that lowercase `pi` means nothing special to Maple?

If you simply meant to use the well-known constant `Pi` instead, then your problem is just with the syntax of assuming.

I split the lines below, just to format them more nicely here. You could enter each a a single longer line.

```
restart:

int( ((1 - r*cos(x-t)))/(1+r^(2)-2*r*cos(x-t)),
     x=0..2*Pi ) assuming t>=0, r>=0, t <=2*Pi, r<=1;

                                2 Pi
```

It turns out that the assumptions on `t` are not necessary for that result to obtain.

```
restart:

int( ((1 - r*cos(x-t)))/(1+r^(2)-2* r*cos(x-t)),
     x=0..2*Pi ) assuming r>=0, r<=1;

                                2 Pi
```

It's understandable that you got the `assuming` syntax not right. You mistakenly cobbled something together that looks more like syntax for the `assume` command. Their purposes are related, but the syntax and usage differ.

The `AllSolutions` option allows Maple to compute piecewise results based upon conditions of unknowns in the range of integration (but not just in the integrand). So, it's conceivable that someone might want to do,

```
restart:

int( ((1 - r*cos(x-t)))/(1+r^(2)-2* r*cos(x-t)),
     x=0..2*pi, AllSolutions=true ) assuming t>=0, r>=0, t <=2*pi, r<=1;
```

which will produces a piecewise result with a condition on the unknown parameter `pi`. But that will print confusingly since both `Pi` and `pi` prettyprint the same. Better to use some other unassigned name than `pi`. As I said at the top, you probably meant to use the special constant `Pi` instead.